# What additional conditions are required for convergence in operator norm to imply convergence in trace norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $\mathcal{H},\mathcal{K} $ be a separable Hilbert spaces, and $T_n: \mathcal{H}\mapsto \mathcal{K}$ a sequence of compact operators  satisfying $\|T_n - T\|_{op} \to 0$, with $\|\cdot\|_{op}$ denoting the standard operator norm. Evidently this is not enough to imply that $\|T_n - T\|_1 \to 0$, where $\|\cdot\|_1$ is the nuclear (trace) norm. See e.g. this post: [Convergence in operator and trace-class norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3272353/convergence-in-operator-and-trace-class-norm)

Is it known what (sharp?) additional conditions on top of $\|T_n - T\|_{op} \to 0$ imply that $\|T_n - T\|_1 \to 0$? Are there weaker additional conditions under which $\|T_n - T\|_{op} \to 0$ imply that $\|T_n \|_1 \to \| T\|_1$? What if $\|\cdot\|_{op}$ is replaced with $\|\cdot\|_2$, the Frobenius norm?

Comment: So you want a condition equivalent to $\|T_n-T\|_1\to0$, but it shouldn't use the trace norm? What kind of condition do you expect?

Comment: @MartinArgerami, thanks for the message! I've attempted to clarify-- certainly whatever additional conditions needed might depend on trace norms, but I hope they fall short of assuming the conclusion that  $\|T_n - T\|_1 \to 0$.

Comment: I still wouldn't know what to say really, but you changed $\|T_n-T\|_1\to0$ to $\|T_n\|_1\to\|T\|_1$?

Comment: Thanks @MartinArgerami for thinking about it! Yes I would be interested in both, i.e. what in addition to $\|T_n - T \|_{op} \to 0$ to imply  $\|T_n - T\|_1 \to 0$ or  $\|T_n  \|_1 \to \|T\|_1$. Similarly what in addition to $\|T_n - T \|_{2} \to 0$  imply  $\|T_n - T\|_1 \to 0$ or  $\|T_n  \|_1 \to \|T\|_1$. I've done a bit of research without turning up anything on this, which I find somewhat surprising since there are sort of analogous results on the interplay between various $L^p$ and $\ell^p$ norms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still think there is not satisfactory answer to your question, as vague as it is (very open to be proven wrong, though).

Let us restrict a bit, to see what happens in some cases. We can take $T=0$ with no loss, but I will also assume (big restriction) that all the $T_n$ are simultaneously unitarily diagonalizable (equivalently, that they are normal and mutually commuting). Basically, we are considering the analog problem but in $c_0$.

So we have
$$
T_n=(t_{n1},t_{n2},\ldots).
$$
We have
$$
\|T_n\|_{\rm op}=\max\{|t_{nk}|:\ k\},\qquad \|T_n\|_1=\sum_k|t_{nk}|,\qquad \|T_n\|_2=\sum_k|t_{nk}|^2.
$$
Let us restrict even more, for the sake of simplicity, and also assume that $|t_{n1}|\geq|t_{n2}|\geq\cdots$ for all $n$.

Then
$$
\|T_n\|_{\rm op}=|t_{n1}|,\qquad \|T_n\|_1=\sum_k|t_{nk}|.
$$
The question becomes, in this setting, that we assume that $t_{n1}\to0$, and what conditions will guarantee that
$$\tag1
\sum_k|t_{nk}|\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0.
$$

One example that might be enlightening is to consider
$$
T_n=\big(\overbrace{\tfrac1n,\ldots,\tfrac1n}^{n^2 \text{ times}},0,\ldots\big).
$$
Then $$\|T_n\|_{\rm op}=\frac1n,\qquad\text{ while } \qquad \|T_n\|_1=n$$
for all $n$.

Other than talking specifically about the series (that is, prescribing directly that $\|T_n\|_1\to0$), I cannot see what condition would guarantee $(1)$.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! It is nice to consider this simple case. It seems in this case the result would follow by the dominated convergence theorem if for example there exists a dominating summable sequence of $t_{n,i}$. It is good to know, although surprising and sad, that there does not seem to be a general theory here...

Comment: You should think of the operator norm as an analog of the infinity norm. Think of $\mathbb C[x]$ as restricted to $x\in[0,1]$; then the uniform closure $\mathbb C[x]$ is $C[0,1]$. But if you consider $\|\cdot\|_1$-limits, you get all of $L^1[0,1]$.